# How to omit perfect forwarding for deduced parameter type?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, perfect-forwarding, template-argument-deduction

Let's say I have some function a parameter type (or several parameter types) of type which I want to be deduced. Also I want different behavior based on the fact is it rvalue or lvalue. Straightforwardly writing it leads to an obvious (for experienced people) trap because of perfect forwarding:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
void f (T &&v) // thought to be rvalue version
{
   // some behavior based on the fact that v is rvalue
   auto p = std::move (v);
   (void) p;
}

template <typename T>
void f (const T &v) // never called
{  
   auto p = v;
   (void) p;
}

int main ()
{
    std::vector<int> x = {252, 135};
    auto &z = x;
    f (z);
    std::cout << x.size () << '\n'; // woah, unexpected 0 or crash
}
```

Even though sneaky nature of such behavior is already an interesting point but my question is actually different - what is good, concise, understandable workaround for such situation?

If perfectly forwarded type is not deduced (e.g. it's already known template parameter of an outer class or something like this) there's well known workaround using `typename identity<T>::type&&` instead of `T&&` but since the same construction is a workaround for avoiding type deduction it doesn't help in this case. I could probably imagine some sfinae tricks to resolve it but code clarity would probably be destroyed and it will look completely different from the similar non-template functions.

Comment: what crash? `size` don't have preconditions therefore can be called on moved vectors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SFINAE hidden in a template parameter list:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T
        , typename = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_lvalue_reference<T>{}>::type>
void f(T&& v);

template <typename T>
void f(const T& v);
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8e9ba20d5c1499e)

---

SFINAE hidden in a return type:

```
template <typename T>
auto f(T&& v)
    -> typename std::enable_if<!std::is_lvalue_reference<T>{}>::type;

template <typename T>
void f(const T& v);
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51ab6e5da3d7079c)

---

In [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) `typename std::enable_if<!std::is_lvalue_reference<T>{}>::type` can be shortened to:

```
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_lvalue_reference<T>{}>
```

Anyway, even in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) you can shorten the syntax with an alias template if you find it more concise:

```
template <typename T>
using check_rvalue = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_lvalue_reference<T>{}>::type;
```

[**DEMO 3**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5648528bcddae264)

---

With [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) constexpr-if:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T&& v)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T>) {}
    else {}
}
```

---

With [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) concepts:

```
template <typename T>
concept rvalue = !std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T>;

void f(rvalue auto&& v);

void f(const auto& v);
```

[**DEMO 4**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XmOstvHoWfQBYYyM)

Comment: Actually that's pretty good because you have to write it only for rvalue version and no garbage needed for lvalue one. The only problem probably is that the people in general more familiar with move semantics than with what enable_if does and why it should be used in this case but anyway at least this solution is relatively short.

Comment: @Predelnik depending on what *behavior* you implement in your function, maybe you could get away with a single overload that calls `std::forward<T>(t)` once ?

Comment: yeah I understand that in general using `forward` should be priority in cases such as this however I've met with similar code at least   a couple of times, and that is the reason for asking a question.

Answer (score 4):

How about a second level of implementation:

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

// For when f is called with an rvalue.
template <typename T>
void f_impl(T && t, std::false_type) { /* ... */ }

// For when f is called with an lvalue.
template <typename T>
void f_impl(T & t, std::true_type) { /* ... */ }

template <typename T>
void f(T && t)
{
    f_impl(std::forward<T>(t), std::is_reference<T>());
}
```

Comment: Checking only if `T` is a reference fails with `f<std::vector<int>&&>(std::vector<int>{});`

Comment: That's surely working solution and also without sfinae. However I can point the following minor problems: if function in question will happen to be constructor or operator, naming wouldn't probably be that obvious as in this case. Also someone not that familiar with this pattern may add something to the first level function thinking that it works only with rvalues (not very likely I guess but still it may cause a bit of confusion). Also you need to fix small mistake mentioned by @PiotrSkotnicki.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki: Yes, you don't want to specify the template argument explicitly. If that's a use case, you need to adjust the code.

Comment: @Predelnik: If you want to support explicit template arguments, then yes, you'll need to modify the code to check only for lvalue references. (That's a weird usecase, though, and you should either let the arguments be deduced or forwarded.) Anyway, you know what to do...

Answer (score 2):

I think SFINAE should help:

```
template<typename T,
         typename = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value>::type>
void f (T &&v) // thought to be rvalue version
{
   // some behavior based on the fact that v is rvalue
   auto p = std::move (v);
   (void) p;
}

template <typename T>
void f (const T &v) // never called
{  
   auto p = v;
   (void) p;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. Forgot about it. Corrected the answer.